# How can I efficiently use numpy to carry out iterated summation

Tags: python, numpy, cython

## Definition of Problem

I can express the problem I am trying to solve like this:

Given A [Nx1] and n[Nx1] and x[Mx1], I want to carry out this operation

```
S = sum([A[i]*x**n[i] for i in range(len(n))])
```

with the use of numpy. I think I can do this using something like broadcasting in numpy, but I can't make sense of the numpy docs.  Can someone help me figure out how to do this effciently in numpy?

I have a working cython solution for this problem below that is pretty fast and I wonder if I can do it more easily using numpy and avoid cython entirely.

## Cython solution

Here is a working implementation for this problem using cython to demonstrate the problem:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef  sum_function( double [:] A, double [:] x, double [:] n, double [:] out):
    cdef int i,j
    cdef int Nx = len(x)
    cdef int Nn = len(n)

    out[:] = 0

    for i in xrange(Nx):
        for j in range(Nn):
            out[i] += A[j]*x[i]**n[j]
```

Comment: Your calculation of `S` produces a scalar--it sums *all* the elements--but in the cython function, `out` is a vector that is the same length as `x`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser , If I am not mistaken, the code I have sums the numpy arrays generated from A[i]*x**n[i] entries, and thus the result is again a numpy array with the dimensions of x

Comment: Indeed, you are correct if `sum` is the built-in Python function.  I was using ipython with the `--pylab` option, which puts `numpy.sum` in the namespace of the interactive shell.  The default behavior of `numpy.sum` (in particular, with the default `axis=None`) is to convert its argument to a numpy array and sum *all* the elements.  I'll clean up my answer.

Comment: In general I never import all the functions from numpy since then you can get clashing with common functions (I don't use ipython that much).  np.blah is short enough that it doesn't clutter the code too much and makes the intent much more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.sum(A * x.reshape(-1, 1)**n, axis=1)`:

```
In [40]: A
Out[40]: array([ 1.,  2., -1.,  3.])

In [41]: n
Out[41]: array([ 2.,  1.,  1.,  3.])

In [42]: x
Out[42]: array([  5.,  10.,   1.])

In [43]: S = sum([A[i]*x**n[i] for i in range(len(n))])

In [44]: S
Out[44]: array([  405.,  3110.,     5.])

In [45]: np.sum(A * x.reshape(-1, 1)**n, axis=1)
Out[45]: array([  405.,  3110.,     5.])
```

`x.reshape(-1, 1)` has shape (3,1), and `n` has shape `(4,)`, so the (broadcast) result of `x.reshape(-1, 1)**n` has shape (3,4); column *k* contains `x**n[k]`.  `A` has shape (4,), so `A * x.reshape(-1, 1)**n` has shape (3,4); element (i,j) of that product contains `A[j]*x[i]**n[j]`.  The desired result is the sum of this array along `axis=1`.

Here's the cython version with the same data:

```
In [46]: out = np.zeros_like(x)

In [47]: sum_function(A, x, n, out)

In [48]: out
Out[48]: array([  405.,  3110.,     5.])
```

Comment: According to his Cython code, the `sum` needs an `axis=` keyword rgument.

Comment: Brilliant!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Especially the ``axis=1`` kwarg

Comment: Minor detail: reshape(-1,1) is more cleanly and efficiently written as x[:,None]

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: Heh, says who? :)  Actually, the idiomatic spelling of that form would be `x[:, np.newaxis]` (where `np.newaxis` is None).  But I've always preferred `reshape`.

Comment: As far as efficiency is concerned: so says your processor, who will have to perform additional logic to figure out what you meant by that minus one. A filtered reducing product on your shape tuple, plus one division, to be precise. Minor indeed, but using more text to ask the computer to compute something you already know, and could communicate with one very clear and ubiquitous symbol, rubs me the wrong way. Sorry, I guess im just in a pedantic mood ;)

Comment: On my computer, `x.reshape(-1, 1)` is almost twice as fast as `x[:, None]`.  `reshape` is pretty explicit, but admittedly it requires that you know how the -1 is handled.  Indexing with `None` to create a trivial extra dimension always seemed a bit mysterious to me.  Once you know the convention, it works, but it is not initially obvious.

Comment: The actual performance difference is so tiny that constructing a benchmark that generalizes to real world scenarios is nearly impossible I think. But at least conceptually, reshaping requires a longer chain of deductions to resolve. Knowing what the new -1 axis should be requires you to consider all other axes, whereas the colon just says 'keep this the same', which is really the message we are trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting will only work if M=N, or if x is scalar. If M > N, just do

```
S = sum(a*x[:N]**n)
```

Similarly for M < N.